# Getting value out of a key. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
recipes: {
    "Cupcakes": {name: "Cupcakes", available: true, ingredients: "", directions: ""},
    "Cookies": {name: "Cookies", available: false,  ingredients: "", directions: ""},
    "Sushi": {name: "Sushi", available: true,  ingredients: "", directions: ""},
    "Apple_Pie": {name: "Apple_Pie", available: true,  ingredients: "", directions: ""}
},
```

How can I get the ingredients out of the key "Sushi"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
var ingredients = recipes.Sushi.ingredients;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `object['property']` is the same as `object.property`. Note that you would use the first notation for non-standard property names like: `var ingredients = recipies['Multiple Words'].ingredients`.

Comment: @PHPglue yup good point, I didn't include that because he had the _ in between Apple and Pie, but absolutely!

Comment: I got the following error.... recipes.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ingredients' of undefined

Comment: @Ayechan_San is there a "Sushi" key in your recipes object?

Comment: Yes. I just pass in a name and name could be anything in the recipe

Comment: I did what you suggested and wrote var ingredients = recipes.name.ingredients and got the error above.

Comment: You'll get that error if `name` is not a key in recipes. What `name` did it fail for?

Comment: I figured it out. I have a list of clickable items, and instead of passing in just the name, I also passed in the ingredients, and just displayed as usual. recipes.Sushi.ingredients only works if I specially mention the name of the recipe. If I'm passing in the name through a function and say recipes.name.ingredients, it throws the error. Anyway, I figured it out and thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

should be

if your recipes is assigne to a

```
var myrecipes = {recipes: {
"Cupcakes": {name: "Cupcakes", available: true, ingredients: "", directions: ""},
"Cookies": {name: "Cookies", available: false,  ingredients: "", directions: ""},
"Sushi": {name: "Sushi", available: true,  ingredients: "", directions: ""},
"Apple_Pie": {name: "Apple_Pie", available: true,  ingredients: "", directions: ""}}
},

console.log(myrecipes.recipes.Shushi);
```